# I run the folowing code and get a empty sell in jupyter notebook , (the plot does not show but the space is there!)

Tags: python

```
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
import chart_studio
returns.iplot()
```

when I run the code , i get an big empty space in notebook's cell with no plot meanwhile last week it worked correctly

(returns is my Dataframe)

Comment: Welcome! Please consider this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `returns.iplot()` instead of `return.iplot()`